# How to write code for uploading file in selenium webdriver type="button"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML code:

```
<td class="field">
<input id="setupfiletext" class="forminput" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="setupfile"/>
<input id="setupfile" class="forminput" type="file" name="setupfile" accept=".txt" style="display: none"/>
<input id="setupfileclick" class="forminput" type="button" name="setupfileclick" value="Browse"/>
</td>
```

I have tried using the following code in Selenium webdriver:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='setupfileclick']")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("setupfiletext")).sendKeys("D:\\clinicagenofiles\\txt2.txt");
```

...but it is not working.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Please [include all relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: using java- above code is written for button

Comment: class="field">
<input id="setupfiletext" class="forminput" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="setupfile"/>
<input id="setupfile" class="forminput" type="file" name="setupfile" accept=".txt" style="display: none"/>
<input id="setupfileclick" class="forminput" type="button" name="setupfileclick" value="Browse"/>

Comment: Please [add this information to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28473371/edit), rather than appending it to the comments. Also, you should [indent your code by 4 spaces](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode) so that it is formatted correctly.

Comment: that's normal: the input is in readonly. If the role of setupfileclick is to enable the text input, show the javascript. otherwise what does setupfileclick?